# Access coins stored at Cryptobridge?

Tags: exchanges, decentralized-exchanges

I have just discovered, albeit far too late, that Cryptobridge has closed.

Now, there is a lot to say about this particularly dodgy move, but I won't and I'll keep this simple:

**How can I access the coins stored in the Cryptobridge wallet?**

I saved the .bin file and can access my Bitshares account via OpenLedger, but the only coin listed is Bitshares. Bitcoin is just one of the coins that are/were stored in that wallet.

I've searched around and a few forums say it's possible by logging in to another exchange. Well, that's what I've done and that clearly didn't work.

I am hoping that this simple question has a simple answer, even if that answer is: "You can't."

Comment: P.S. I searched for this question on here but couldn't find it. I found that quite surprising.

Comment: Do you have a backup for the wallet of any sort? Eg a mnemonic seed phrase, or a wallet.dat file or equivalent. If yes, you can probably recover your coins. If no, you're out of luck.

Comment: The .bin file is the equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How can I access the coins stored in the Cryptobridge wallet?**

According to [Cointelegraph](https://cointelegraph.com/news/cryptobridge-closes-down-and-waves-relaunches-dexs-face-tough-times) in late 2019:

> [CryptoBridge] announced that all of the firm’s services and servers will be terminated within two weeks. Users will be able to withdraw funds from the exchange until Dec. 15 — the last day of operation.

I'm not familiar with CryptoBridge but [it seems like](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2015949.0) they acted as custodian of Bitcoin and other cyptocurrencies and used their Bitshares blockchain to keep track of their customer's funds. If so you don't have any direct way to recover control over the money that you transferred to CryptoBridge.

Any keys or backups you have might only give you control over their Bridgecoins and those appear to [have no value now](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/bridgecoin/btc) and are probably not exchangeable into other cryptocurrencies.

---

> **I am hoping that this simple question has a simple answer, even if that answer is: "You can't."**

I think that is the simple answer.

Comment: As I suspected. Thanks.

Comment: Yet another ‘DEX’ that is actually fully centralized around a custodian/admin of some sort... what a sham. ‘DEX’ is pretty much a marketing buzzword at this point, not a technical specification. Sorry for your losses :(